# Sorting a struct array based on int

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, sorting, struct

I'm kinda stuck when trying to sort `int` number. I'm trying to display the items based on its number (nummer). The `int main` and `#includes` are in the program, just couldn't copy them. Is there a preferred why to handle this issue and can someone explain it, I been trying for a while now haha. Thanks

```
char *oneline, *tok;
char envara[512];
char delim[] = ",";
FILE *fp;
int i;

struct vara
{
    int nummer;
    char namn[100];
    float pris;
    float volym;
    char typ[100];
    char stil[100];
    char forpackning[20];
    char land[20];
    char producent[50];
    float alkoholhalt;

} items[100];


if ((fp = fopen("varor.csv", "r")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Filen varor.csv gick inte att öppna\n");
    exit(-1);
}

for (i = 0; i < 100 && fgets(envara, 512, fp); i++)
{
    envara[strlen(envara) - 1] = '\0';
    oneline = strdup(envara);

    tok = strtok(oneline, delim);
    items[i].nummer = atoi(tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    strncpy(items[i].namn, tok, (max(strlen(tok), sizeof(items[0].namn))));
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    items[i].pris = atof(tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    items[i].volym = atof(tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    strncpy(items[i].typ, tok, strlen(tok));
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    strncpy(items[i].stil, tok, strlen(tok));
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    strncpy(items[i].forpackning, tok, strlen(tok));
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    strncpy(items[i].land, tok, min(strlen(tok), sizeof(items->land)));
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    strncpy(items[i].producent, tok, strlen(tok));
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
    items[i].alkoholhalt = atof(tok);

    printf("nummer: %d\n"
        "namn: %s\n"
        "pris: %f\n"
        "volym: %f\n"
        "typ: %s\n"
        "stil: %s\n"
        "forpackning: %s\n"
        "land: %s\n"
        "producent: %s\n"
        "alkoholhalt: %f\n\n",
        items[i].nummer,
        items[i].namn,
        items[i].pris,
        items[i].volym,
        items[i].typ,
        items[i].stil,
        items[i].forpackning,
        items[i].land,
        items[i].producent,
        items[i].alkoholhalt
    );

    free(oneline);
}

fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything which looks like sorting.

Comment: What aspect of the problem has you stuck?

Comment: no, i had to delete that part. it was all wrong. I´m looking for a alternative, from the begginning if you have the time

Comment: I guess insertion sort will do? but how do i apply it nicely?

Comment: Why not use [qsort()](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2)?

Comment: David, i will take a look at it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try making this into a [mcve], please! <3

Comment: I´ve tried to work it out with qsort, but im getting nowhere.

Comment: can someone give me at least a start

Answer (score 1):

```
int cmpVara(const struct vara *left, const struct vara *right)
{
      // quick & dirty way to compare two ints.
      return (long) left.nummer - (long) right.nummer;
}

// :
// :

       qsort(items, i, sizeof(vara), cmpVara);
```

`i` is the number of elements in `items`.

Comment: curiosity - why the cast to long?

Comment: @pm100 If the ints were close to INT_MIN and INT_MAX, the difference could wrap around, give the inverse of what we want.  Assuming longs are bigger than ints (not guaranteed), casting to long should prevent that.